# Calling Async REST api from spring batch processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, asyncresttemplate

I wrote a spring batch job that processes List of Lists.

Reader returns  List of List.
Processor works on each ListItem and returns processed List.
Writer writes stuff to DB and sftp from List of List.

I have a use case where I call Async REST api from spring batch processor. 
On ListenableFuture response I implemented LitenableFutureCallback to handle success and failure, which works as expected, but before the async call returns something, ItemProcessor dosen't wait for call backs from async api and returns object(List) to writer.

I am not sure how to implement and handle async calls from ItemProcessor.

I did read about AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter, but I am not sure if that is something I should use in this scenario.

I also thought of calling get() on ListenableFuture response from AsyncRestTemplate, but as per documentation it will block the current thread until it receives the response.

I am seeking for some help on how should I implement this. Code snippet below:

Processor:

```
public class MailDocumentProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<MailingDocsEntity>, List<MailingDocsEntity>> {

... Initialization code

@Override
public List<MailingDocsEntity> process(List<MailingDocsEntity> documentsList) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Entering MailingDocsEntity processor");


    List<MailingDocsEntity> synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(documentsList);


    for (MailingDocsEntity mailingDocsEntity : synchronizedList) {
        System.out.println("Reading Mailing id: " + mailingDocsEntity.getMailingId());

       ..code to get the file

         //If the file is not a pdf convert it
         String fileExtension = readFromSpResponse.getFileExtension();
         String fileName = readFromSpResponse.getFileName();
         byte[] fileBytes = readFromSpResponse.getByteArray();

         try {

             //Do checks to make sure PDF file is being sent
             if (!"pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(fileExtension)) {
                 //Only doc, docx and xlsx conversions are supported

                     ...Building REquest object
                     //make async call to pdf conversion service
            pdfService.convertDocxToPdf(request, mailingDocsEntity);

                 } else {
                     logger.error("The file cannot be converted to a pdf.\n"
                        );

                 }
             }


         } catch (Exception ex){
             logger.error("There has been an exception while processing data", ex);

         }

    }
    return synchronizedList;
}

}
```

Async PdfConversion Service Class:

```
@Service
public class PdfService{


   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("MicroServiceAsyncRestTemplate")
   AsyncRestTemplate microServiceAsyncRestTemplate;

   public ConvertDocxToPdfResponse convertDocxToPdf(ConvertDocxToPdfRequest request, MailingDocsEntity mailingDocsEntity){

        ConvertDocxToPdfResponse pdfResponse = new ConvertDocxToPdfResponse();


            try {

                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

                HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);



                ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<ConvertDocxToPdfResponse>> microServiceResponse = microServiceAsyncRestTemplate.postForEntity(batchMailProcessingConfiguration.getPdfUrl(), entity, ConvertDocxToPdfResponse.class);

                ConvertDocxToPdfResponse resultBody = microServiceResponse.get().getBody();
                microServiceResponse.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<ConvertDocxToPdfResponse>>()  {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<ConvertDocxToPdfResponse> result) {
                        ...code to do stuff on success


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                        pdfResponse.setMessage("Exception while retrieving response");

                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                String message = "There has been an error while issuing a pdf generate request to the pdf micro service";
                pdfResponse.setMessage(message);
                logger.error(message, e);
            }


        return pdfResponse;
    }

}
```

My original batch job was synchronous, i am converting to Async to faster processing.
I did try to look for similar questions, but could not find enough information.
Any pointers or help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did read about AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter, but I am not sure if that is something I should use in this scenario.

Yes, `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter` are suitable for your use case. The `AsyncItemProcessor` will execute the logic (your rest call) of the delegate `ItemProcessor` for an item on a new thread. Once the item completes, the `Future` of the result is passed to the `AsynchItemWriter` to be written. The `AsynchItemWriter` will then unwrap the `Future` and write the item. The advantage of these components is that you don't have to deal with `Future`s wrapping, unwrapping, etc yourself.

You can find:

- More details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors
- An example here: https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/blob/master/single-jvm-demos/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/scalingdemos/asyncprocessor/AsyncProcessorJobApplication.java

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this today.

Comment: Async call to rest api from my processor class is not the return type. I work on List of some records from DB, I send file contained in the item for pdf conversion. When it comes back, I update the list item, which is part of returned List which goes to Writer. I did implement the AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter,  but not sure how to wire the Future returned to the writer..

Comment: Update: I could finally implement Async Rest api call from processor. I call asynaRest api from AsyncItemProcessor and save the Future retured to the POJO itself which I am working on and to be sent to writer. In writer, I do get() on ListenableFuture object. I choose get over callback methods because I want definite response from the API at this point and write back to DB. Let me know if you see scope of improvemnts in my approach.