# process multiple object read through ItemReader at same time(concurrently) with Spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-admin, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to read data from the database, and run process on each object concurrently.

> My config as below,

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(new Listener(videoDao))
            .flow(step1()).end().build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<VideosDTO, VideosDTO>chunk(3)
            .reader(databaseVideoItemReader(null))
            .processor(new Processor())
            .writer(new Writer(videoDao))
            .build();
}



 @Bean
 @StepScope
ItemReader<VideosDTO> databaseVideoItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[userId]}") String userId) {
    logger.info("Fetching videos for userId:"+userId);
    JdbcCursorItemReader<VideosDTO> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql("SELECT * FROM voc.t_videos where user_id="+userId+"AND job_success_ind='N'");
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(VideosDTO.class));
   // databaseReader.open(new ExecutionContext());
   ExecutionContext executionContext= new ExecutionContext();
   executionContext.size();
   databaseReader.open(executionContext);

    return databaseReader;
}
```

> My item process is as below,

```
@Override
public VideosDTO process(VideosDTO videosDTO) throws Exception {
    log.info("processing........" + videosDTO.getVideoUrl());

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe " + "D:\\DRM\\script.sh " + videosDTO.getVideoUrl());
        // .exec("D:\\PortableGit\\bin\\bash.exe
        // D:\\Vocabimate_Files\\script.sh "+videosDTO.getVideoUrl());
        // Thread.sleep(1000);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        p.destroy();
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try (InputStream is = p.getErrorStream()) {
            int in = -1;
            while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) in);
            }
        }
        try (InputStream is = p.getInputStream()) {
            int in = -1;
            while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) in);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    return videosDTO;
}
```

> writer is as below:

```
    @Override
public void write(List<? extends VideosDTO>videosList) throws Exception {

    for(VideosDTO vid:videosList){
        log.info("writting...."+vid.getVideoUrl());
    }

}
```

> Suppose if there are 3 Objects fetched from DB this code first
>   complete process on first object,than second and than third than
>   starts writing.I want to Run process on the three object concurrently
>   at same time,than perform writing operation.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the details of your custom Reader/Processor/Writer, I think what you're looking for is [a multi-threaded Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/index-single.html#multithreadedStep).

As also described in the above linked documentation in order to make your step multi-threaded (meaning reading/processing/writing each chunk in a separate thread) you first need to register a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("myAsyncTaskExecutor");
}
```

and then register this task executor in your Step's builder:

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<VideosDTO, VideosDTO>chunk(3)
            .reader(databaseVideoItemReader(null))
            .processor(new Processor())
            .writer(new Writer(videoDao))
            //making the Step multi-threaded
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a multi-threaded step like suggested by @dimitrisli is the way to go. In addition to that, another way is to use the [`AsyncItemProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors) (in combination with an `AsyncItemWriter`).

A similar use case (calling a rest endpoint asynchronously from the processor) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52309260/5019386 where I gave some more details.

Hope this helps.